Translate a python string such as 'a.b.c=v' into a dictionary
How can I read a 'key=value' strings such as ['foo=bar', 'a.b.c=ddd'] and translate them in to a dictionary? The dictionary should either be updated if the key already exists, or have the new key added if it doesn't.
The example given in the paragraph above should translate to the following...
{'foo': 'bar', 'a': {'b': {'c': 'ddd'}}}

But it is instead translates to this incorrect dictionary...
{'foo': 'bar', 'a': {}, 'b': {}, 'c': 'ddd'}

How can I fix the code in the example under the comment 'Set the master config value for the current setting'?
Example Code
### For context - in reality I use an argument parser with two args.
###   --config-file - Path to a YAML configuration file. If present,
###     this file will be read into Python as a dictionary called
###     `master_config`. If not, an empty dictionary of the same name
###     will be created.
###   --configs - Single 'key=value' settings that will be read into
###     `master_config` and either override settings defined in the
###     YAML configuration file, or set a value.

master_config = {'foo': 'baz'}
configs = ['foo=bar', 'a.b.c=ddd']

for config in configs:

    # Split the setting into key and value.
    k, v = config.split('=', 1)

    # Split the key, if it's nested.
    ks = k.split('.')

    # Set the master config value for the current setting.
    l = len(ks)
    for i, x in enumerate(ks):
        if i != l-1:
            if not master_config.get(x):
                master_config[x] = {}
        else:
            master_config[x] = v

print(master_config)


We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a specific question - which will come out of your best attempt to understand and locate a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. If you are "struggling with" one section of code, we should see that section specifically, with minimal, but complete setup work that allows us to test that code directly - i.e., not embedded in some other nested loop following argument parsing, and not dependent on a file that we don't have.

Wow, that's just ridiculous. There was one problem that was clearly defined and other users were obviously able to understand the question as one kindly provided an answer within minutes. While it may not be important to you, context is vital to others otherwise provided answers may not be valid. Lack of context also makes questions and answers less useful for those seeking solutions in the future.

The problem is not "understanding the question". The problem is using the site as intended, by creating questions that advance the goal of the site as described in the [tour]. Context justifies why you want to solve the problem - it doesn't explain what the problem is. Aside from that, your opening statement describes a problem that clearly breaks down into a series of logical steps; if you only want to ask about one step, then you should properly focus the question on that step.

So how to your mind is the question not focused? I have stripped out as much of it as I possibly can without taking away examples, yet you still keep the question closed. Please also consider that if the goal of the site doesn't fit users of the site, then perhaps it should be reviewed.

@DavidGard Didn't end up doing this, but I did consider using an infinitely nested defaultdict.

@MichaelCao, I did see that earlier today, but (having never used it) it seems that it would only work for keys that are not set, rather than partial keys. Thanks.

Work backwards to create the nested dict and then update your master_config
k = 'a'
v = 'ddd'

ks = k.split('.')[::-1]

master_config = {}

if len(ks) == 1:
    master_config[k] = v
else:
    nested_dict = {ks[0]: v}
    for x in ks[1:]:
        nested_dict = {x: nested_dict}
    
    master_config.update(nested_dict)

Edit: New solution using a recursive function to deal with key collisions. It will attempt to update the deepest key that stores a dictionary. If the key does not exist or the value is not a dictionary, it will overwrite instead.
k = 'foo.buzz'
v = 'fizz'

ks = k.split('.')

master_config = {'foo': {'bar': 'fizz'}}

def update(config, *args):
    if len(args) == 2:
        k, v = args
        config[k] = v
    else:
        k, *args = args
        if k not in config or not isinstance(config[k], dict):
            config[k] = {}

        return update(config[k], *args)

update(master_config, *(ks + [v]))


Upon further review, this code appears to not quite work as expected. Rather then updating an object within master_config, it instead overwrites it. For example, if the value of master_config is {'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}} and I have k = foo.buzz and v = fizz, then master_config will now be {'foo': {'buzz': 'fizz'} - the bar property will be gone.

Ah... so it would break if you did with args like foo.bar=bizz foo.buzz=fizz. I've added a new solution.

Thanks, I too was working on a very similar recursive solution which I added as an answer a few moments ago.

The solution below will update a dictionary in the following circumstances -

The whole key exists, e.g. master_config = {'a': {'aa': 'AAA'}} and settings = ['a.aa=AAA'].
The key partially exists, e.g. master_config = {'b': 'BBB'} and settings = ['a.aa=AAA'].
The key does not exist at all, e.g. master_config = {} and settings = ['c.cc=CCC'].

Note that settings are read in order, so if the key in settings[0] is overwritten by the key in settings[1], it will be the key/value defined as settings[1] that will appear in the dictionary.
def update_dict_value(obj: any, keys: list, value: any=None) -> None:
    '''Update the value of a key in a dictionary.

    :param obj: The dictionary object to update.
    :param keys: A list elements that make up the key. For elements
    that do not exist or are not a dict, an empty dict will be created.
    :param value: The value to apply to the key in the dict.
    '''

    if not isinstance(obj, dict):
        raise TypeError("Object to update must be <class 'dict'>.")

    # If there is only one key in `keys`, simply set the `value`.
    if len(keys) == 1:
        obj[keys[0]] = value

    # Otherwiase we're dealing with nested keys.
    else:
        # Ensure the key is a dictionary. It may not be if -
        #  - This is a new key `obj`.
        #  - The key exists in `obj`, but is not a dictionay.
        if obj.get(keys[0]) is None or not isinstance(obj[keys[0]], dict):
            obj[keys[0]] = {}

        # Recursivly call this function.
        update_dict_value(obj[keys[0]], keys[1:], value)

master_config = {'a': {'aa': 'AAA'}, 'b': 'BB'}
settings = ['a.aa=AAA', 'b.bb=BBB', 'c.cc=CCC']

for setting in settings:
    k, v = setting.split('=', 1)
    ks = k.split('.')
    update_dict_value(master_config, ks, v)

print(master_config)

